# Is there a way to debug dalvik code (AOSP) while an application is running on our device. Does GDB help for this purpose

Tags: android, debugging, gdb, dalvik

I would like to know what's happening inside the dalvik directory of android open source while an application is running on our device.I know that the dalvik part in AOSP gets compiled to libdvm.so. I don't want to debug the android application but need to know where everything gets started (related to interpreter and JIT) when an application runs.

While an application is running on the device, its dex code is getting interpreted and detected hot traces are passed to JIT compiler for converting to m/c code.Is it possible to see this via debugger while running the app on the device. I hope the requirement is not confusing.

I tried using gdbclient on host and gdbserver on device.

1. Gave the `/system/bin/dalvikvm` as executable. But its parsing the dalvikvm folder in AOSP
   which I think is the commandline execution part of dalvik.
2. Then I gave `libdvm.so` as the executable. It loaded the symbols. But where should I give 
   the breakpoints.

After starting the application in the device, it says program not being run.

Have anyone done this kind of debugging? Please help me with your methods and suggestions.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=android+dalvik+gdb

Answer (score 0):

i have used ndk and was able to debug native code . U need to use gdb client for that ndk version . But as for dalvik , it has some tests and tools to debug , but not tried using gdb..